# size of TCHAR array in DWORD

Tags: visual-c++, tchar, dword

I have following VC++ code. How to clalculate size of TCHAR in DWORD which will not fail at runtime.

```
HKEY hKey = 0;

DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

TCHAR buf[255] = {0};

DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);


if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
{
    auto ret = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("\\Device\\Serial0"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize );
    ...
}
```

Then what should value for `bufSize`. IS following code is still correct ?

```
DWORD bufSize = sizeof(buf);
```

Comment: Related: `RegQueryValueEx` does not guarantee a `NULL` terminated string. Be sure to terminate it.

Comment: Often, the way to do this is to *query* the size of the data and then create an appropriate sized buffer. [RegQueryValueEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value for bufSize will be 510 bytes.
U should understand that TCHAR is typedef to WCHAR i.e. of 2bytes. Whenever we use sizeof operator, it will give the size in bytes.

Note: If UNICODE_STRING is defined then TCHAR is taken as 8 bytes otherwise its 16 byes holding wide characters.

your problem here can be solved by calling **RegQueryValueEx** API twice. The last argument of the mentioned API is [_in_out] does means pass this as null and retrieve the size first. Then in the next call to API, pass size and retrieve lpdata. ((If the buffer specified by lpData parameter is not large enough to hold the data, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA and stores the required buffer size in the variable pointed to by lpcbData))